# How to Show Specific Days on Altair Chart time axis

Tags: python, altair

I am plotting data of stock price over time using altair, my dataframe doesn't contain data for weekend days, and this appears as gaps on chart. How can I make the Chart plot only Monday to Friday for every week and remove gaps

altair documentation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.